# PhpStorm thinks <div> is open but it isn't with blade directives

Tags: php, html, phpstorm, laravel-blade

Here is the code:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="errorClass">
@else
    <div class="cleanClass">
@endif
<p>Some stuff</p>
</div>
```

The above code make PhpStorm register that there is an open `<div>`. Any way to fix this bug?

This is making it frustrating to use when it comes time to refactor code.

I installed the Blade extension hoping that would help - it didn't. PhpStorm reports:

> Element div is not closed.

Any way to make PhpStorm smarter?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26903 and possibly https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28250 . In short -- HTML parser does not know anything about Blade directives and what they do. Possible workaround: instead of duplicating `div` tags with conditions around them .. just use those conditions on class names.

Comment: Thanks - that works but it is gross looking..Oh well better than nothing.

Comment: Don't use PHP Storm *kappa*

Comment: @Jonathan what do you use?

Comment: @Radmation I'm on Sublime Text 3 and love it personally - but I know PHP Storm is very good - just prefer ST

Comment: Thanks for deleting your answer. For future reference, most editors don't mind deleting their wiki answers in favour of a "real" one, since wiki material does not generate rep points, but real ones do. Thus, your real answer might have generated you some points, but my wiki answer won't generate me any at all!

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the tip. I will make sure I do this in the future! I don't mind as long as the answer is there. I have enough points to get a few questions answered;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

### Workaround

This works but is not easy to read.

```
<div
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
         class="errorClass"
    @else
         class="cleanClass"
    @endif
>
    <p>Here is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

### Best Situation for readability

A simple ternary would do the job better.

```
//Open as normal
<div class="{{ count($errors) > 0 ? 'errorClass' : 'cleanClass' }}">
    <p>This is some text</p>
</div>
```